# roscpp message_filters ApproximateTime API questions

Tags: ros, message-filter, ros-kinetic, approximatetime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have two questions regarding using message_filters ApproximateTimePolicy. From the [example](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#ApproximateTime_Policy), it is not quite clear how I can specify the delay (in seconds) between messages that they can be synchronized. There are `setAgePenalty`, `setInterMessageLowerBound`, and `setMaxIntervalDuration` calls. I winder which one I should be using.

The second question is that I need to instantiate the Synchronizer with `SimpleFilter<sensors_msgs::Image>` instead of `message_filter::Subscriber`. Can anyone provide me with a code snippet how to do this? Sorry I'm not very good with c++ template, hence, the question.

Thanks for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284758/roscpp-message_filters-approximatetime-api-questions/) by [jlin](https://answers.ros.org/users/30223/jlin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2018-03-07

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chmod777](https://answers.ros.org/users/130711/chmod777/) on 2022-12-29**:
Official doc about message_filters ApproximateTime: https://wiki.ros.org/message_filters/ApproximateTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Regarding your first question, you want to set the `setMaxIntervalDuration`. As far as I understand from a quick look at the sources, a higher value for `setAgePenalty` makes the algorithm more sloppy for older messages (to get them out of the queue faster) and `setInterMessageLowerBound` allows to set a minimum delay between messages of a single input of your filter (messages arriving faster than that will be dropped).

As for the second question, you can just feed a SimpleFilter as an input to your Synchronizer:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/subscriber_filter.h>
#include <message_filters/pass_through.h>
#include <message_filters/simple_filter.h>
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>


void callback(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& imagemessage1,
    const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& imagemessage2) {

}


int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "test_synchronizer");
  ros::NodeHandle nodehandle;

  image_transport::ImageTransport imagetransport{nodehandle};

  image_transport::SubscriberFilter imagesubscriber1;
  imagesubscriber1.subscribe(imagetransport, "/image1", 32);

  image_transport::SubscriberFilter imagesubscriber2;
  imagesubscriber2.subscribe(imagetransport, "/image2", 32);

  message_filters::PassThrough<sensor_msgs::Image> passthrough(imagesubscriber2);
  message_filters::SimpleFilter<sensor_msgs::Image> & simplefilter = passthrough;

  using MyPolicy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<
      sensor_msgs::Image, sensor_msgs::Image>;
  MyPolicy mypolicy(32);
  mypolicy.setMaxIntervalDuration(ros::Duration(1.e-3));
  message_filters::Synchronizer<MyPolicy> synchronizer{
      static_cast<const MyPolicy &>(mypolicy), imagesubscriber1, passthrough};
  synchronizer.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2));

  ros::spin();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Maarten](https://answers.ros.org/users/34054/maarten/) with karma: 206 on 2018-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jlin](https://answers.ros.org/users/30223/jlin/) on 2018-03-09**:
Thanks so much! Somehow the program failed to link with undefined reference to `image_transport::ImageTransport::ImageTransport(ros::NodeHandle const&)'. I'm on ROS 1 kinetic. Probably my environment is not set up right.

**Comment by [Maarten](https://answers.ros.org/users/34054/maarten/) on 2018-03-09**:
You probably just need to add image_transport to your package.xml file (`<depend>image_transport</depend>`). And install the ros-kinetic-image-transport package if it's not yet installed, but I suppose you would get a compiler error and didn't get to the linking phase if it wasn't installed.